# How are eigenvalues and eigenfunctors of operators like Laplacian understood?

Tags: spectral-theory, laplacian

Normally you would consider eigenvectors only of operators from the same space to itself.

But the Laplacian is usually defined on $C^2$ into $C$, which is a supset of $C^2$.
Which leads to my question, in spectral theory, how are eigenvalues of Laplacian usually defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvalues and eigenvectors can be defined in the usual way:  $f$ is an eigenvector of $L$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if $L f = \lambda f$.  In this case $f \in C^2$, and $L f$, which a priori would be in $C$, happens to be in $C^2$ as well.  In fact, using elliptic regularity, $f$ is $C^\infty$.

Comment: So, even though it's not exactly an operator on $C^\infty$, we don't lose anything when it comes to eigenvalues (and eigenfunctions) when considering it as such. Thank you!